# What happens if a dependent current source has a negative value?

Tags: current-source

[image]

When I try to solve some circuit exercises, I receive a negative number for the dependent current source (meaning the direction of the source is wrong, maybe).

Is this a wrong solution or is nothing wrong (meaning the direction of source draw in the exercise is not important -- if the value is negative, just redraw the direction of source)?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

When you don't know the direction of the current then you make an assumption. If it turns out to be negative then, yes, the current is going the wrong way. You don't have to fix it as long as the value shows that it is going the opposite direction.

[image: schematic]

<sup>[simulate this circuit](/plugins/schematics?image=http%3a%2f%2fi.stack.imgur.com%2fn31ai.png) – Schematic created using [CircuitLab](https://www.circuitlab.com/)</sup>

The circuits above are identical other than the direction and sign of their current sources.

Comment: Yeah, In high school (there is no current source in my program) I used to solve several problems with the current direction (whenever it is negative, etc... like you said). But now when I see what's called "current source", I strict myself to get a number that is positive with my current source symbol. So, this is the first time I see a current source symbol with "-"1A, turn out current source also has a negative value ! Thank you so much.